# how to check if user is already logged in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I have maintained session by implementing SessionAware and using sessionMap. I have added userName to sessionMap. But Still when I am logged in one Tab and in another tab if i put the url of login action, it still asks for login. when i put the login action url , i want it to show you are already logged in.

Comment: Show your code, how you are adding user details into session?

Comment: The usual thing to inform a result about what action has been done while executing is to send a message. Consult the action support how it could be useful to supply the action message to the result and make it available for the view to display it.

Comment: Look for attribute in the session?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the check in your action class from which you are getting redirected to login page. If you are directly loading the login page without going to any action class then you can use `s:if` tag to redirect to some other page or show your message.

```
<s:if test='%{#session.USERID != null}' >
        // do something
</s:if>
```

A much better option is to use a [login intercepto](http://www.journaldev.com/2210/struts-2-interceptor-tutorial-with-custom-authentication-interceptor-example)r to check every request for active session.